# tipo datos en crystal reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

quiero cambiar tipo de dato en un dataset para que se muestre en el informe de tipo numero es en crystal reports y c#, este tiene un dataset en c# pero al jalarlo en el crystal solo me da los campos en formato cadena y necesito en numero para algunas sumatorias que realiza el reporte alguna manera de cambiar los tipos de datos se puede hacer directo en el codigo del query:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                //a.CFECHA between '"+Program.strFechaIn+"' and '"+Program.strFechaFi+"' and 
                Reportes Ds = new Reportes();
                da.Fill(Ds, "Reportes1"); 
                Reportes.SetDataSource(Ds);
                this.crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Reportes;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienes que ir a la vista de tu dataste, da click derecho y selecciona propiedades. Al seleccionar tu dato lo cambias en la opción de DataType.

Comment: muchas gracias por su respuesta me quedo claro y se soluciono son su respuesta

Comment: Excelente, si se solucionó puedes marcar mi respuesta como resuelta para futuras referencias.